# How to get json nested in nested array?

Tags: arrays, json, handlebars.js

I need "source" with handlebars, I tried {{trailers.youtube.source}} but no response, suggestions?

```
  "trailers" : { "quicktime" : [  ],
      "youtube" : [ { "name" : "Trailer",
            "size" : "Standard",
            "source" : "vP9QCAcGy7Y",
            "type" : "Trailer"
          } ]
    },
```

Comment: `{{trailers.youtube[0].source}}`? Youtube is an array. *disclaimer:* I know nothing about handlebars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
trailers.youtube[0].source
```

to get the first element from that array.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is `{{trailers.youtube.0.source}}`, handlebars can't work with `[]`.